# Infinite for loop in Python

Tags: java, python, infinite-loop

I'm new to Python. Actually I implemented something using Java as shown below.

```
 for(;;){
 switch(expression){
     case c1: statements

     case c2: statements


     default: statement
 }
}
```

How do I implement this in Python?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use while loop:

```
 while True:

      if condition1:
            statements
      elif condition2:
            statements
      ...
      else:
            statements
```

Answer (score 6):

```
while True:
    # do stuff forever
```

Answer (score 1):

Formally, there's no `switch` statement in Python; it's a series of nested `if-elif-else` statements.

Infinite loops are accomplished by the `while True` statement.

All together:

```
while True:
    if condition_1:
        condition_1_function
    elif condition_2:
        condition_2_function
    elif condition_3:
        condition_3_function
    else:  # Always executes like "default"
        condition_default_function
```

Comment: Beware that there is no fall-through in `if/elif/else` like there would be in `switch`

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a way to iterate infinitely in python you can use the itertools.count() function like a for loop. http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/itertools.html#itertools.count

Comment: This looks useful for infinite generator expressions like `('CONSTANT' for i in itertools.count(0, 0))` as an argument to functions expecting a generator. You don't have to define a separate function that has the while True loop.

Comment: @hobs To achieve that, you would use `itertools.repeat('CONSTANT')`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
while True:
    if c1:
        statements
    elif c2:
        statements
    else:
        statements
```

or

```
var = 1
while var == 1:
    # do stuff
```

Comment: Normally it's more implicit to use the boolean `True` instead of an integer if we're talking infinite loops.  This way, the intent is clearer and easier to debug (who's to say that the value of `var` may not change over time?).

Comment: It is true, and using the boolean is (probably) the blessed way. That is just another example of achieving the same thing. `var` can change, but that is also up to the developer to not change it if she chooses to go that way. ;-)

Comment: But why have `var` at all? If the point is to have a value that is always equal to 1 to create an infinite loop, why not just say `while 1 == 1`? And having done that, it's absurd not to just write `while True`.

Comment: @Ben:  We could go even *further*, and say `while 1`, which is tantamount to `while True`.  But that's quite besides the point! :)